# Cannot access a local directory using the URL from Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, url, command-prompt

How can I access a [local] directory using the URL syntax from Windows command prompt?

E.g.:

```
dir file:///D:/temp/test/
```

returns:

> Invalid switch - "/".

While it is fine in a web browser.

I tried with all combinations of forward and backslashes, without success.

The purpose is to make my batch script work with both local and remote paths.

Comment: Try adding `""` so like `"file:///D:/temp/test"`

Comment: Where does it say that the `dir` command understands URLs? Off topic.

Comment: @CloseVoters, why do you think it's off topic? It's a question about writing a batch script, which does qualify as programming to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The low-level file system functions on Windows do not understand URL protocols. Neither does cmd.exe. Only local paths and [UNC paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Universal_Naming_Convention) (`\\server\share\file.ext`) are supported.

Parts of WinInet, Shell32 and ShlWapi APIs supports various protocols but that is not going to help you in this case.